# Was warp technology ever used as a weapon?

Tags: star-trek, weapon, warp

In any Star Trek canon, was warp technology ever used to intentionally damage something? According to physics as we know it, the ability to deliver a payload (even a relatively small one) at relativistic speeds would be devastating to virtually any target (trust me, don't stand in the way of the LHC beam). Since warp drive allows ships to travel even *faster* than light, one would think that would only increase the damage it could do if slammed into another ship.

Was warp drive ever used to propel a projectile (or even a full ship) into a target? If no, is there any reason given as to why not?

Comment: Hm I don't think any of the answers there really explained it to my satisfaction, but I'll definitely acknowledge it's the same question. I'm also curious why that one didn't pop up in the recommendations as I was writing this.

Comment: It does answer your question an object at warp has NO speed therefore NO kinetic energy, a collision at warp would be no more dangerous than a warp core breach see this answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82948/68984

Comment: or this answer http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13340/68984